# Fetching HTML without reordering the attributes

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Im using Test Driven Development to test some JS funciton.

This is the JS

```
CardReader.prototype.lockDevice = function() {
    this._buttonElement.disabled = true;
    this._statusElement.innerHTML = " ";
    this._statusElement.innerHTML = 'Waiting for NFC card <img id="image" alt="Waiting" src="/img/waiting.gif" height="16" width="16">';
    this._hardwareAccessor.lockDeviceRequest(this.lockDeviceCallback, this);
};
```

and this is the test:

```
CardReaderTestCase.prototype.assertWaitingMessageIsAsExpected = function() {
    assertEquals('Waiting for NFC card <img id="image" alt="Waiting" src="/img/waiting.gif" height="16" width="16" />', this.statusElement.innerHTML);
};
```

But when I run the test, turns out the attributes width and height have been reordered to the beginning, making the assert fail.

Is there any way to grab the HTML without having the attributes mixed up?

Comment: can you write your hard-coded tests in the same format as the browser, or does it vary?

Comment: innerHTML is rarely the same as the literal text, and different browsers render  it differently, adding or removing quotes, capitalizing some lower case items, leaving off end-tags and especially the xhtml end slash ('/>' becomes '>')in image elements

Comment: In that case, of course, the assert passes. But I cant guess always how is going to be transformed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guaranteed order of attributes and you are dealing with serialization of XML. You should just check properties you need, like the image width.

```
CardReaderTestCase.prototype.assertWaitingMessageIsAsExpected = function() {
    assertEquals(this.statusElement.childNodes[1].width, 16);
    // Even check the HTML but be more relaxed
    assertEquals(this.statusElement.innerHTML.indexOf("Waiting for NFC card"), 0);
}
```

Comment: I guess Ill have to do it that way. Thanks!